# Magento 2 migration tool MySQL server has gone away

Tags: database, error, ce-1.7.0.2, magento-2.0, magento2-migration-tool

I'm migrating data from magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2 and get the following error:

> MySQL server has gone away

[image]

Comment: Please check your MySQL "wait_timeout" variable to make sure MySQL is not closing the database connection early.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved it by increasing the following value in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` mysql configuration file:

```
max_allowed_packet=4000M # just set it to 4000M because on my dev machine i don't care
```

Be carefull to not change the mysqldump option, there is also a `max_allowed_packet`

I also added this line to set the `wait_timeout` in the same configuration file:

```
wait_timeout=6000
```

Comment: Late to this party.  Could you confirm with SELECT @@max_allowed_packet  size is 4G?  Most version documentation indicates the Range is up to 1G.  Error log many indicate at startup a different max available.

Comment: I can't confirm this. Maybe it just uses the max value from 1GB when setting it to a bigger value. But 1GB will be way enough anyways.

Comment: @bpoiss can you confirm the path for my.cnf file. i am using xampp server. migration m1.9.3.6 to m2.3.3